# Solved: Routine with Do While and For make a unknow error GCC Core dump (Segment fault)

Tags: c, gcc

After compiling this program with GCC (Linux or Windows or online test compiler), it fails in different ways each time it runs.  I don't understand where I made the mistake.

On Ubuntu Linux, the program crashes without printing an answer.

On Windows 10 (MSYS), it loops indefinitely without printing any message.

On an online compiler I tried, it fails with a segmentation fault (and core dump and exit code 139).

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  float riga[1][3];
  int ciclo = 2;
  int calcolo;
  float totale;
  int codice = 0;
  int quanti = 1;
  int prezzo = 2;

  printf("\n Inserendo una quantita pari a 0 si conclude con il totale");

  do {
    codice++;
    printf("\n Numero: %d Inserire la quantita:", codice);

    scanf("%f", &riga[codice][quanti]);

    if ( riga[codice][quanti] < 1 ){
      printf("\n Calcolo del totale.");
      ciclo = 1;
    } else {
      printf("\n Numero: %d Inserire il prezzo:", codice);
      scanf("%f", &riga[codice][prezzo]);
    }

    //printf("\n Quantita: %f Prezzo: %f", riga[codice -1][quanti], riga[codice -1 ][prezzo]);
    //printf("\n Ciclo = %d", ciclo);

  } while( ciclo != 1 );

  printf("\n Totale in calcolo");

  for ( calcolo = 1; calcolo < (codice + 1); calcolo++){
    //printf("\n Prezzo = %f",riga[calcolo][prezzo] );
    totale = totale + (riga[calcolo][prezzo] * riga[calcolo][quanti]);  
  }
  printf("\n Totale: %f", totale);

  return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: `riga[codice][quanti]` is only valid if `codice` is `0`, because the first dimension has only 1 element, but you increment `codice` to `1` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.don't use uninitialized variables and you should initialize `totale`.

2.don't pass boundaries of your array or it will cause undefined behavior.

here in this declaration `float riga[1][3];` ,first dimension has only one element.Your increment here `codice++;` is invalid you don't have `riga[1][num]` you only have `riga[0][num]`.So remove this line `codice++;` and also check in your while condition that you won't scan more than `3` elements for second dimension of array.

here

```
for ( calcolo = 1; calcolo < (codice + 1); calcolo++){
    totale = totale + (riga[calcolo][prezzo] * riga[calcolo][quanti]);
}
```

again you are passing boundaries of array. `calcolo` could only be zero.

as @John Bollinger said underlying point about arrays: they are indexed from 0, not from 1.

Comment: Underlying point about arrays: they are indexed from 0, not from 1.

Comment: Omg many times I have read the code without realizing that the mistake was so obvious Thank you very Mutch

Comment: @ExagonX feel free . no need for thanks , but if this was helpful accept the answer.

Comment: Hi, When I Post an answer some time I see different color in the source code and some time all code in grey, do you know what I have to do for show the code with different color ?

Comment: @ExagonX no actually.it was my problem too ,I'm a new user to this site too.